# CallRedirectionService Implementation not working

Tags: android, service, android-10.0

[Android Q](https://developer.android.com/preview/features#call-redirect) has introduced `CallRedirectionService` API - seems like one of the way 3rd party apps can use it is to cancel calls and reroute them over VoIP - essentially intercepting the phone calls.

I was trying to implement this class as below

```
public class CallMonitorService extends CallRedirectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "CallMonitorService";

    public CallMonitorService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaceCall(Uri uri, PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle, boolean b) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPlaceCall:### ");
    }


}
```

As you can see I am overriding `onPlaceCall` which is abstract method in the `CallRedirectionService` and simply keeping a log statement to check/test if this callback method hook is invoked by Android framework.

I added this service in my Manifest.xml as well as below, which is what is documented in the Source code of `CallRedirectionService` class

```
<service
                android:name=".CallMonitorService"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REDIRECTION_SERVICE"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.CallRedirectionService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

My Guess is that when Android system places a outgoing call this `onPlaceCall` will be invoked and then we can write our custom code to do further action on the outgoing call. Am not 100% sure if this is how `CallRedirectionService` is supposed to work - By the way there is no example available in developer.android.com for how to implement `CallRedirectionService` as of this writing. I set both  `minSdkVersion 29` `targetSdkVersion 29` in my `build.gradle`

However when the call is made - the `onPlaceCall` inside my Service is not getting invoked.

I am using Android Q Emulator for testing as i do not have Android phone running Android Q to test this - can this be not tested on Android emulator by placing a emulated phone call or What else Am I missing?

Comment: For Android version after 10  CallRedirectionService is used. But Do you know how to achieve this for below 10 version?

Comment: Exactly in which method inside onPlaceCall() can get user dialed number? Because I have tried all methods inside that but only get null

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that at the moment documentation is not full and sample in documentation is not correct. 
To fix this, in your AndroidManifest it is needed to change

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REDIRECTION_SERVICE"
```

to

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CALL_REDIRECTION_SERVICE"
```

This permission is incorrectly written inside the google documentation for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallRedirectionService.html currently.

Also, it is required to ask user to allow your application play this role. In google documentation this part missing at the moment :

```
 RoleManager roleManager = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);}
```

Comment: Ok - i will try out above changes

Comment: Is this still supported? I see it marked in grey here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallRedirectionService

Comment: For an application targeting version before and after android Q what would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: @MisterJack49 Me too have the same doubt. Do you able to find anything?

Comment: @Sandhiya for now I use the deprecated way it's not ideal but for now it does the job https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html

Comment: @MisterJack49 Thank you so much!!! Will refer the link

Comment: @MisterJack49 I have two doubts in using that broadcast.  1) Not able to start an activity from BroadcastReceiver 2) If My app cleared from background, then Broadcast Receiver not triggered(For this I have tried Background Service But No use).. Do you have any idea about this.

Comment: Are you sure about this permission, @Alek Kutsko, because after applying this permission, I am not able to make any outgoing calls. android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CALL_REDIRECTION_SERVICE"

Answer (score 4):

Got it working (looking [here](https://github.com/nexmo-community/parental-control-app)). The next code will block all outgoing calls (it's just a sample...) :

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (!isRedirection())
            roleAcquire(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION)
    }

    private fun isRedirection(): Boolean {
        return isRoleHeldByApp(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION)
    }

    private fun isRoleHeldByApp(roleName: String): Boolean {
        val roleManager: RoleManager?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
            return roleManager.isRoleHeld(roleName)
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun roleAcquire(roleName: String) {
        val roleManager: RoleManager?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (roleAvailable(roleName)) {
                roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
                val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(roleName)
                startActivityForResult(intent, ROLE_ACQUIRE_REQUEST_CODE)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Redirection call with role in not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun roleAvailable(roleName: String): Boolean {
        val roleManager: RoleManager?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
            return roleManager.isRoleAvailable(roleName)
        }
        return false
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ROLE_ACQUIRE_REQUEST_CODE = 4378
    }
}
```

**MyCallRedirectionService.kt**

```
class MyCallRedirectionService : CallRedirectionService() {

    override fun onPlaceCall(handle: Uri, initialPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle, allowInteractiveResponse: Boolean) {
        Log.d("AppLog", "handle:$handle , initialPhoneAccount:$initialPhoneAccount , allowInteractiveResponse:$allowInteractiveResponse")
        cancelCall()
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.callredirectionservicesample">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyCallRedirectionService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CALL_REDIRECTION_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.CallRedirectionService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```