# Set my app as the default Dialler not asking options in Android 10 (Q)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, telephonymanager, android-10.0

I'm currently having trouble getting my app to send the user a dialogue to set the default Dialler on API 29 but the same code is working fine below Android 10 (Q).

I test this [No response from intent to prompt user to set default handler for SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575173/no-response-from-intent-to-prompt-user-to-set-default-handler-for-sms) example as well but not working on mine. Then I followed https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers but not solved my problem. Is there any special change for API level 29 or above to let the user set the default app?

> Here's my working code (for below Android 10)

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE);
        if (!getPackageName().equals(telecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
                    .putExtra(EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

> What I'm getting in logcat is here

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the API changed, see the note in the previous API here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER

And see here for the new API:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager

basically, you need to do something like:

```
RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE);
Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER);
startActivityForResult(Intent, CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_CODE); // you need to define CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER as a static final int
```

and then you catch the response by implementing `onActivityResult` in your activity.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'm getting compile time error `Non-static method 'createRequestRoleIntent(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context` at `createRequestRoleIntent`. Would to help me why am I getting this?

Comment: I solved it with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548666/callredirectionservice-implementation-not-working) but the direction was yours. Credit goes to you. Thank you so much. I have no words to thank you. I had got stuck for 14 days.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the minimum that I needed to do in order make my app (baresip VoIP client) eligible as default Phone app:

In AndroidManifest.xml I added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I added these two intent filters to MainActivity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="tel" />
  <data android:scheme="sip" />
</intent-filter>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I added this new service:

```
<service
  android:name=".InCallService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE" >
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
    android:value="true" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_CAR_MODE_UI"
    android:value="false" />
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I didn't check if the meta-data entries are really needed.

Then I implemented the InCallService service like this:

```
package <my package>

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder

// This is needed in order to allow choosing <my app> as default Phone app

class InCallService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        TODO("Return the communication channel to the service.")
    }
}
```

Finally, if there is need to request default dialer role from the app (and not only from Android Apps settings, it can be done like this (at API level 29+):

```
val dialerRoleRequest = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "dialerRoleRequest succeeded: ${it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK}")
}
        
if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER) && 
        !roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER))
    dialerRoleRequest.launch(roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER))
```

Removing of default dialer role needs to be done from Android Apps settings.