# Android 11 - CallRedirectionService not getting triggered

Tags: android, android-api-31

We need to invoke a service when an outgoing call is placed so that we can use the target number to show certain additional information. As per Android documentation, CallRedirectionService should be used. However, after declaring a custom service as depicted in documentation, we find that the custom service is not getting triggered. Please let us know what we are doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

I referred to this link as well but not clear on the answer. There is a mention to role acquisition but I did not find that in Android documentation. Please direct me to the relevant page if available.

[CallRedirectionService Implementation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548666/callredirectionservice-implementation-not-working)

### Manifest.xml

```
    <service android:name="<mypackage>.CustomCallService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CALL_REDIRECTION_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.CallRedirectionService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

### Custom service code

```
@Override
public void onPlaceCall(@NonNull Uri handle, @NonNull PhoneAccountHandle initialPhoneAccount, boolean allowInteractiveResponse) {

    System.out.println("Outgoing:" + initialPhoneAccount + ":" + handle); //Call does not reach here
    placeCallUnmodified();

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CallRedirectionService Implementation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548666/callredirectionservice-implementation-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read that link again, maybe I understood it wrong. The documentation does not seem to refer to any "Role acquisition", do I need to do that ?

Comment: Maybe but I am not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Kotlin:**

Your implementation of the CallRedirectionService seems correct. I understand that **the only step missing is the role request and acquisition**.

You can prompt the user to give you the CallRedirectionService role by using the [**RoleManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager) class.

In this example below, we are requesting this role as soon as the MainActivity is created:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (!isRedirection())
            roleAcquire(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION)
  }
}
```

The following functions shall be used:

```
    private fun isRedirection(): Boolean {
        return isRoleHeldByApp(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION)
    }

    private fun isRoleHeldByApp(roleName: String): Boolean {
        val roleManager: RoleManager? = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
        return roleManager!!.isRoleHeld(roleName)

    }

    private fun roleAcquire(roleName: String) {
        val roleManager: RoleManager?
        if (roleAvailable(roleName)) {
            roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
            val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(roleName)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Redirection call with role in not available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

    }

    private fun roleAvailable(roleName: String): Boolean {
        val roleManager: RoleManager? = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
        return roleManager!!.isRoleAvailable(roleName)
    }
```